# Add element to json in localStorage

Tags: json, local-storage

I have:
 `localStorage.xxx = JSON.stringify([["something","hello"],["something2","hello2"]]);`.
How can i add a new array in the JSON `xxx` like `["something3","hello3"]`.

Comment: are you looking for something more clever than parsing the json kept in localStorage, modifying your object/array, then stringifying it again before putting it back in localStorage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
var arr = JSON.parse( localStorage.xxx ) ;
arr.push( ["something3","hello3"] ) ;
localStorage.xxx  = JSON.stringify( arr ) ;
```